# Algorithm to count unit triangles in large composite shape

Tags: python, algorithm, shapes, pseudocode, brute-force

I need to write a brute-force algorithm to count the number of unit triangles in a complex shape. The shape is created each iteration by adding triangles to surround all outer edges.

[image: Example]

The shape in iteration number n would look as above and the outputs would be 1 4 10 respectively.

Unfortunately I do not really know where to begin, first thought was to create 2 classes; a triangle and a grid class consisting of multiple triangles. However adding the outer triangles would prove difficult to do past n = 3 as some edge pairs will only need 1 shared unit triangle.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind solution was simpler than I ever imagined as triangles added increase by 3 every time a simple for loop to add from n=1 worked easily enough.